# DTS Script Task: Runtime Error in SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I have a problem with the SSIS package.
When the process hits Execute Script Task I’m receiving the following error.

[image: Photo of an error]

The process is even not reaching the breakpoint which is in the C# script. However, I found out that if I comment major part of a code, the script is working

[image: Commented script]

The line after which an error occurs is that where I use  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

[image: Line which causes an error]

I saw posts with similar problems where the error was caused by wrongly assigned ReadOnlyVariables/ReadWriteVariables but in my case, the variables are assigned correctly.
I guess that there is a problem with libraries which I use but have no idea how to deal with that.

[image: Added namespaces]

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What is the connection string?  I translated the exception which says : the target of the invocation raised an exception.  All we know is the connection string is probably bad.  It may be a language issue since the error indicate a Culture Issue.

Comment: Please use text (copy&paste) instead of images of rendered text. Hyperlinks are welcome for details&reference, but [a question post should include everything inviting useful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Divide and conquer. Hard code the connection string. Any difference? No - then you can rule out variables. Try the connection string directly in Azure Storage Explorer. Try a test connection string.